# Having problems with ng-controller when shifting from 1.2.16 to 1.5.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-controller

this is a angular 1.2.16 script i tried:

in the head:

```
    <script>
        function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.value = "Lorem ipsum";
        }
    </script>
```

and in the body:

```
    <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
       {{value}}
    </div>
```

When i try to use 1.2.16 cdn everything goes fine but when i use 1.5.5 or anything above 1.2.16 it goes off and just outputs {{value}} instead of lorem ipsum. 

I need to get the same output in 1.5.5 or even 2 so what to do?

Comment: I think this is old version. try use new version for controller.

Comment: Ya, but i don't know how to do a newer version controller that's the issue

Comment: see this http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in v1.5.5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        angular.module("app", []);

        angular.module("app")
                .controller("ExampleCtrl", exampleCtrl);

        function exampleCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.value = "Lorem ipsum";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    {{value}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

See the docs for more information on [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Answer (score 0):

This is way to do in newer version

```
<div ng-app='test'>
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
   {{value}}
</div>
</div>


   <script>
   var app = angular.module('test',[]);

    app.controller('ExampleCtrl',function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.value = "Lorem ipsum";
    }
  )

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use controller like this.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyController', [function() {
  // ...
}]);
```

read more [here migrate 1.2 to 1.3](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3)

Comment: thanks, by the way do you think learning 1.2.16 is a good idea?